# C# .Net How to retarget application to the .Net Framework one has installed (from console, without Visual Studio)

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, nuget-package

Someone has sent me a solution with some C# project files in it. I use only the command line interface of dotnet and I haven't got Visual Studio installed because of lack of memory on my computer. When trying to build the solution or just an individidual project file with the command

```
dotnet build
```

I get the following error:

```
MSBuild version 17.4.1+9a89d02ff for .NET
  Determining projects to restore...
  Nothing to do. None of the projects specified contain packages to restore.
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.102\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1229,5): error MSB3644: The reference assemblies for .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2 were not found. To resolve this, install the Developer Pack (SDK/Targeting Pack) for this framework version or retarget your application. You can download .NET Framework Developer Packs at https://aka.ms/msbuild/developerpacks [D:\Informatik\NachhilfeInfoUni\C#MohammadTyp\ClientApp034 (2)\ClientApp034\Business.Model\Business.Model.csproj]

Build FAILED.

C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.102\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1229,5): error MSB3644: The reference assemblies for .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2 were not found. To resolve this, install the Developer Pack (SDK/Targeting Pack) for this framework version or retarget your application. You can download .NET Framework Developer Packs at https://aka.ms/msbuild/developerpacks [D:\Informatik\NachhilfeInfoUni\C#MohammadTyp\ClientApp034 (2)\ClientApp034\Business.Model\Business.Model.csproj]
    0 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:00.50
```

If, possible, I just want to retarget my application and not install anything new. But I would also be happy to be able to download the correct .Net framework preferably with the Command Line (e.g. a command like dotnet upgrade ) Below is the project file. I have already tried just remove the line with the TargetFrameworkVersion. I have also failed figuring out my installed .Net-Framework following this tutorial:
[Tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/how-to-determine-which-versions-are-installed)

Any help is appreciated

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProjectGuid>{1F1F9B49-8ED7-4F08-9E82-7E0048581B7A}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
    <RootNamespace>LernCard.Business.Model</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>Business.Model</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.7.2</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
    <Deterministic>true</Deterministic>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" />
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data" />
    <Reference Include="System.Net.Http" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="BusinessObjects\Card.cs" />
    <Compile Include="BusinessObjects\CardCollection.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup />
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
</Project>
```

Comment: Seems you installed .NET 7 which is cross-platform and before we call it .NET Core, but the project is .NET Framework 4.7.2 (old dotnet) and you need to install it here: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet-framework/net472

Answer (score 3):

Let's read the error message:

> error MSB3644: The reference assemblies for .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2 were not found. To resolve this, install the Developer Pack (SDK/Targeting Pack) for this framework version or retarget your application. You can download .NET Framework Developer Packs at https://aka.ms/msbuild/developerpacks

So, you have two options:

1. Install the aforementioned developer pack
2. Retarget your application to *not* use .NET Framework

Point #1 is fairly straightforward, but that means installing new things. Keep in mind that the developer pack isn't a full Visual Studio installation, and it's not as big. Most importantly, having the .NET Framework *runtime* installed is not sufficient (which is what the tutorial you have linked deals with, so it's irrelevant).

But, if you *really* want to avoid installing it (which, wise choice, since .NET Framework is old and stinky), then onwards to point #2: retargeting. Which in this case really means *migrating* because it's not necessarily a straightforward process. Microsoft has a [guide on the topic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/).

Most notably, you'll have to change the .csproj file to use the [SDK-style project format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/project-sdk/overview). Microsoft has a tool to automate some (or maybe even all) of the work, the [.NET Upgrade assistant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/upgrade-assistant-overview), but you'll have to (you guessed it) *install* it, which might be a bridge too far.

Then, depending on what your app is doing, there might be some other breaking changes you have to take into account, but by then you can probably get away with just compiling it and see what breaks. Looking at your `.csproj`, seems like it's a very small class library with a few C# files and no external dependencies, so it's unlikely to be a tricky process. In fact, it's so small, maybe you could get away with just creating a new .NET 7 project and copying the files over.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot! I could download the developer pack and it was indeed not that big and it worked afterwards!